# jQuery mobile get data from remote server with PHP

Tags: php, android, jquery, mobile

My problem is:
I have mobile application using jquery+jquery mobile+phonegap. In this app I have several pages with forms. I want to submit this forms to remote server where is php file for handling variables and it return simple text as output. My big problem is that I don't know how get this data in my application without redirecting to Android browser. I search over internet and I can't find how figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should be making an ajax request from jquery to the php file that handles the request and will return the appropriate response. Take a look at the jquery documentation to see how to make an ajax request, where the url field is the url of the php file and the data field is the variables you want to pass to the php file.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/